# ASP.NET ResolveUrl returns only root

Tags: asp.net, url, url-mapping

I am wondering why `ResolveUrl()` function removes href attribute value and whatever I pass as a URL string ultimately leads to http://localhost:PORT. For example:

```
<a href="<% ResolveUrl(@"~/Home.aspx?param=1");%>">SomeText</a>
```

resolves to

```
<a href>SomeText</a>
```

**[EDIT] A workaround that helped me**, but didn't solve the actual problem:

I didn't put the URL in `ResolveURL` function. I added the `runat="server"` instead. Like so:

```
<a href="~/Home.aspx?param=1" runat="server">SomeText</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single-quotes like this:

```
<a href='<%= ResolveUrl(@"~/Home.aspx?param=1") %>'>SomeText</a>
```

Comment: I have added the EQUALS symbol after the % sign in the code above. In certain databound contexts the # symbol can be used instead. This is probably why it was not working for you.

Comment: Also, the semicolon at the end is unnecessary. Removed.